# How to generate a PDF file preview using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

Please advice how can I render the preview of the existing PDF file to a Bitmap so I can display it on my form?

### Many thanks in advance.

BR,
Murat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTexhSharp cannot render a PDF to an image, your best bet would be to have a look at GhostScript.

I have a c# wrapper for the GhostScript dll that that do this, email me at the address on my profile page and I will email it to you.